# Unable stop Firebase service in my service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
public class FirstService extends Service {

    private static String TAG = "Service";
    Boolean isLoggedIn;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "FirstService started");
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
        if(isLoggedIn){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
            startService(intent1);
        }
        else
        {
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class));
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class));
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
        if(isLoggedIn){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class));
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class));

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "FirstService destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
        if(isLoggedIn){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class));
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "FirstService tastremove");
    }
}
```

How can I stop FCM service in my custom service? First service starts, but in background, my service is not working and the FCM Service automatically starts and sends me notification even if I am not logged-in in my app?

Answer (score 2):

FirebaseMessagingService doesn't have an active role in receiving the messages. It is only used to process the messages after they are received.

Even if you stop it Android would start it again when a new messages arrives.

If you want your application to stop receiving messages you can stop sending or you can delete your FCM token with `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteId()`

Comment: One moment: use `deleteInstanceId()` instead of `deleteId()`